# Google Compute Engine, always running?

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2012

does the virtual machine on Google Compute Engine continue to run along with the settings and task schedules i setup without me opening or connecting to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, GCE workloads are meant to run continuosly by default. You can [stop/shutdown](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/stop) or [suspend (Alpha functionality)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instances/suspend) VM instances manually, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, VM instance continue to run if you did not manually shut it down. You may also perform a shutdown scripts using this link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript.